# jquery remove javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to remove html element using jquery using `$(element).remove();`. But there is a javascript code, like `setinterval()`, which should be removed. Yes, I can do `clearInterval()` for particular that case, but what if other types of javascript code?

```
     <script>
     var baseurl = '...';
     jQuery(function(){
        new AjaxUpload('#upload_button', {
           action: baseurl,
           onSubmit : function(file , ext){
              jQuery('#...').val(file);
           },
           onComplete: function(file, response){
              // do something....;
           }
        });
     });
     </script>
```

But I am unable to do so.

Can anybody help me out this problem?

Comment: What other types of code? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Are you referring to event handlers that were bound to the removed elements?

Comment: like some jquery event handler within a script block

Comment: Edit your question and show examples!

Comment: I have edited. Please look at the question again.

Comment: I don't understand how that code relates to your question. Are you saying that that script block is _inside_ the element you are removing? Or that the code in it references the element you are removing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set a id to your script,

```
<script id="sample">
...
</script>
```

and use this code,

```
$("#sample").remove();
```

Comment: Let me try, I will inform you as soon as possible.

Comment: thanks for the down voter for down voting without any comment in accepted answer :)

Comment: Hey @Chamika, Don't know, who down-voted you, but the thing is that, your answer is perfect and really worked for me, and is the answer I was searching for.

Comment: @SoumalyaBanerjee: I know that you are not the person who downvoted. i just put that comment to inform him, it is always better to put a comment when some one down voting. at least for a accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve but in general, removing Javascript code from the document is not the correct way to "switch off" certain functionality you have enabled via Javascript.

For example, if you have set event handlers on certain links and want to undo them, you should use the [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function. Similarly, there would be a way to "undo" everything you've added.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to wrap response in div element and remove all script tags,

```
var el = $('<div>'+response+'</div>');
$('script', el).remove();
response = el.html();
```