# Removing the element from the DOM is not removing the effects of javascript code inside that DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically load the whole page inside one DIV element with the help of javascript. But when I close the div I am using `("#Viewer").remove()` . But still the javascrpit/jquery loaded inside that element is in work. How can I remove the effect of that too.

There is one Viewer DIV. Into which I am loading the whole another page. When I close this I use `("#Viewer").remove()` . When it is first loaded there are some animations and transitions associated with it are happening on other data loaded afterwords.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add some more code you tried!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: **[Cleaning javascript variable scope by removing it's code from DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/786631/500725)**

Comment: Possible duplicate: [jquery remove javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799322/jquery-remove-javascript-code)

Comment: Thanks for the duplicates. It will solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I ead the duplicates suggestes this one works

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="myScript">
</script>
```

and removing with

```
 $("#myScript").remove();
```